# How to fix the [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null. error?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it since the same code worked yesterday. (This is a test app that is using google maps and firebase firestore to save and query markers on a map)

I thought this might have something to do with my flutter install, so I tried using the stable version and the beta version, but the same error occurred in both versions.

**Here is the error:**

```
E/flutter (16809): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
E/flutter (16809): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16809): Tried calling: <=(102.0)
E/flutter (16809): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (16809): #1      GeoFireCollectionRef.within.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:geoflutterfire/src/collection.dart:125:31)
E/flutter (16809): #2      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:442:13)
E/flutter (16809): #3      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:19)
E/flutter (16809): #4      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:68:17)
E/flutter (16809): #5      Iterable.toList (dart:core/iterable.dart:404:12)
E/flutter (16809): #6      GeoFireCollectionRef.within.<anonymous closure> (package:geoflutterfire/src/collection.dart:126:16)
E/flutter (16809): #7      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:219:31)
E/flutter (16809): #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (16809): #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (16809): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (16809): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (16809): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (16809): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (16809): #14     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
E/flutter (16809): #15     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:655:7)
E/flutter (16809): #16     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:597:5)
E/flutter (16809): #17     CombineLatestStream._buildController.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:rxdart/src/streams/combine_latest.dart:293:30)
E/flutter (16809): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (16809): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (16809): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (16809): #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (16809): #22     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (16809): #23     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)
E/flutter (16809): #24     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:224:10)
E/flutter (16809): #25     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (16809): #26     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (16809): #27     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (16809): #28     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (16809): #29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (16809): #30     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (16809): #31     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)
E/flutter (16809): #32     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:224:10)
E/flutter (16809): #33     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (16809): #34     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (16809): #35     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (16809): #36     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (16809): #37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (16809): #38     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14)
E/flutter (16809): #39     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter (16809): #40     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter (16809): #41     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (16809): #42     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16809): #43     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (16809): #44     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (16809): #45     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (16809): #46     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16809): #47     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (16809): #48     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (16809): #49     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (16809): #50     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (16809):
```

Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: FireMap(),
    );
  }
}

class FireMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FireMapState createState() => _FireMapState();
}

class _FireMapState extends State<FireMap> {
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();

  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers =
      <MarkerId, Marker>{}; // CLASS MEMBER, MAP OF MARKS

  BehaviorSubject<double> radius = BehaviorSubject.seeded(100.0);
  Stream<dynamic> query;
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  Future<DocumentReference> _addGeoPoint(LatLng coordinates) async {
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(
        latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude);
    return firestore
        .collection('locations')
        .add({'position': point.data, 'name': 'Yay I can be queried!'});
  }

  void _add() {
//    var markerIdVal = MyWayToGenerateId();
    var markerIdVal = '123abc';
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    // creating a new MARKER
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(24.150, -110.32
//        center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
//        center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
          ),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: markerIdVal,
          snippet: '*',
          onTap: () {
            _onInfoWindowTapped(markerId);
          }),
      onTap: () {
        _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
      },
      draggable: true,
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void _addMarkerAtPosition(LatLng coordinates) {
    _addGeoPoint(coordinates);
    //    var markerIdVal = MyWayToGenerateId();
    var markerIdVal = coordinates.toString();
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    // creating a new MARKER
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: coordinates,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: markerIdVal,
          snippet: '*',
          onTap: () {
            _onInfoWindowTapped(markerId);
          }),
      onTap: () {
        _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
      },
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void _onMarkerTapped(markerId) {
    print('MARKER TAPPED');
  }

  void _onInfoWindowTapped(MarkerId markerId) {
    print('MARKER INFO WINDOW TAPPED');
    //TODO SHOW INFO PANEL
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.NO_HEADER,
      title: markerId.value,
      desc: 'desc',
    )..show();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: LatLng(24.150, -110.32), zoom: 10),
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.hybrid,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            onTap: _onTap,
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 100,
            right: 0,
            child: FlatButton(
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              child: Padding(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.pin_drop,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.green,
//              onPressed: () => _add(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 50,
            left: 10,
            child: Slider(
              min: 100.0,
              max: 500.0,
              divisions: 4,
              value: radius.value,
              label: 'Radius ${radius.value}km',
              activeColor: Colors.green,
              inactiveColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
              onChanged: _updateQuery,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
//          _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.zoomOut());
        subscription.cancel();
        _startQuery();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.zoom_out),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateMarkers(List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
    print(documentList);

    markers.clear();

    setState(() {
      documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
        double distance = document.data['distance'];
        final MarkerId markerId =
            MarkerId(pos.latitude.toString() + '--' + pos.longitude.toString());
        var marker = Marker(
            markerId: markerId,
            position: LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: markerId.value,
                snippet: '$distance kilometers from query center',
                onTap: () {
                  _onInfoWindowTapped(markerId);
                }));

        markers[markerId] = marker;
      });
    });
  }

  _startQuery() async {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    screenWidth *= MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    screenHeight *= MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

    double middleX = screenWidth / 2;
    double middleY = screenHeight / 2;

    var pos = await _mapController
        .getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(x: middleX.round(), y: middleY.round()));
//    var pos = LatLng(24.150, -110.32);

    double lat = pos.latitude;
    double lng = pos.longitude;
    print('getLatLng Position: ' + pos.toString());

    var ref = firestore.collection('locations');
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: lng);

    _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(pos));

    subscription = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
    }).listen(_updateMarkers);
  }

  _updateQuery(value) {
    setState(() {
      radius.add(value);
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    setState(() {
      _mapController = controller;
    });
    if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
      print('PERMISSION GRANTED: LOCATION');
    }
    _startQuery();
  }

  void _onTap(coordinates) {
//    _addMarkerAtPosition(coordinates);
    _addGeoPoint(coordinates);
    _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(coordinates));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

And my pubspec.ymal file:

```
name: googlemapstest
description: Google Maps Test App

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.15
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7



  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  awesome_dialog: ^1.1.3
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+6


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this happens when you tap or do something specific or when the app starts? The error says that there is a null object when using geoflutterfire package (a num maybe)

Comment: It happens with each query, trying to load the coordinates of the markers. I am guessing _startQuery()

Comment: I added rxdart: 0.23.1 as a dependency, that solved the issue, I have no Idea why lol

Comment: I had used the rxdart previously and I thought I wouldn't need it anymore, I guess I was wrong. The programming memes are right, if it works don't touch it :)  Although it didn't work with 0.22.0

Comment: oh yeah rx has the transform method switchMap, maybe that's what you needed and shouldn't delete it. The difference between 0.22 and 0.23 is that the first uses its own classes observables to make the transform method, and 0.23 have extension method, that allow them to use the stream classs of dart and add functions without creating another class, that's why in 0.23 you can use any stream and then add the rx functionality without transforming them to observable (which are depracated now)

Answer (score 3):

You may have not created the object properly.

check for this type of declaration:

```
Foo obj; // wronge way of creating object
obj.method();
```

and change to this

```
Foo obj = Foo(); // Corret way of creating object
obj.method();
```

or

```
Foo obj = new Foo(); // Corret way of creating object
obj.method();
```

PS: the `new` keyword is now optional in Dart.

Comment: send empty array[] in place of null