# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Response<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'. flutter dart

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, response

When I try to parse JSON response received from restful API I get an error as Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Response' has no instance method '[].

```
AuthService().addStaff(new_name, phno, uid, pasword).then((val) {
            print(val)
            print(val["result"]);

            //   if (val['result'] == "successfull") {}
```

addStaff calls an API and get a JSON response , when I print val value I get JSON response as this `

`{"Name":"jj","password":"38b","phoneno":"77","result":"successfull","uploadid":"b","user_type":"staff"}`

but when I try to parse each individual element say val['result'], I get an exception error saying  Class 'Response' has no instance method '[]
How can I parse each individual value from response like Name, password, phoneno, result, uploaded, user_type?
I'm new to flutter dart not much familiar with REST API handling, can anyone help me to achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You need to parse JSON use `jsonDecode()`

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
    
var data = jsonDecode(val);
print(data["result"]);

...
```

[jsonDecode() Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html)

OR

You may have not created the object properly.

check for this type of declaration:

```
Foo obj; // wronge way of creating object
obj.method();
```

and change to this

```
Foo obj = Foo(); // Corret way of creating object
obj.method();
```

or

```
Foo obj = new Foo(); // Corret way of creating object
obj.method();
```

PS: the new keyword is now optional in Dart.

[Original Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657711/how-to-fix-the-errorflutter-lib-ui-ui-dart-state-cc166-unhandled-exception/63423250#63423250)

I hope, this is the solution you are looking for.